# Strip HTML Encodings from a String

Tags: javascript

I am working on a project where I have a URL parameter and I am reading this in from jquery.

I then need to display the value of the parameter to the user but I get the HTML encoding as part of the string.

For example if my string is `my string` I get `my%20string`.

Below is how I am getting the value from the parameter:

```
function getParameterValue(parameter)
{
    var pageUrl = window.location.search.substring(1);
    var urlVariables = pageUrl.split('&');

    for (var i = 0; i < urlVariables.length; i++)
    {
        var parameterName = urlVariables[i].split('=');
        if (parameterName[0] == parameter)
        {
            return parameterName[1];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Google for `decodeuri`

Comment: That's not HTML encoding that's URI encoding

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the Javascript equivalent of decoding the URL: [`decodeURIComponent()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/decodeURIComponent):

```
return decodeURIComponent(parameterName[1]);
```